# CPLEX multi-bite error after Configuration run

Tags: cplex

I am new to OPL and CPLEX. Whenever I try to run my configuration, consisting of simple .mod and .dat, it fails and shows an error ": multi-byte error, wrong encoding? .". I assumed that the problem is with my OPL project encoding, but switching to UTF-8 made 0 change. How can I fix that?
The code is all in latin, so are the paths for the files
the.dat file is as follows:

```
students = { Carwyn, Aidan, Lerato, Dinesh, Harun,Vasu, Bartolomeu, Frigyes, Minato, Helen,Maura, Bertha, Marcelin, Elmira, Vijay };
local = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];
score = [75, 55, 34, 62, 52, 47, 85,78, 74, 61, 93, 89, 84, 29, 65];
ngroups = 5;
```

and the .mod is

```
{string} students = ...;
int local[students] = ...;
int score[students] = ...;
int ngroups = ...;

dvar boolean x[students][1..ngroups];
dvar float beta;

maximize beta;
subject to{
  
  // three students per group
  forall(i in 1..ngroups) sum(s in students) x[s][i] == 3;
  
  // at most one group per student
  forall(s in students) sum(i in 1..ngroups) x[s][i] == 1;
  
  // one local per group
  forall(i in 1..ngroups) sum(s in students) local[s]*x[s][i] >= 1;
  
  // beta is the max-min of group scores
  forall(i in 1..ngroups)
    sum(s in students) score[s]*x[s][i] >= beta;
}

the names for both files are ses2

[File names][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzCgd.png
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in documentation IDE and OPL > Starting Kit > Globalization

You may read

> CPLEX Studio does not support:
>
> •Multibyte names for decision variables, as the CPLEX log file can
> have unexpected behavior if they are used.
>
> •Transcoding from one system to another.
>
> Each operating system deals with its own character encoding, so the
> behavior of string related functions (for example, a string length)
> may vary from one machine to another. The same model executed on
> Windows and on Unix may produce different results. For example, the
> function of a string length could return different numbers if you do
> not ensure that the encodings match.
>
> •Identifiers that contain non-ASCII characters.
>
> For example, French accents are not allowed. OPL identifiers are
> restricted to the ASCII character set.

and I ran your model and got

```
beta = 196;
x = [[0 0 0 0 1]
             [1 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 1 0 0]
             [0 1 0 0 0]
             [1 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 1 0]
             [0 0 0 1 0]
             [0 0 1 0 0]
             [0 1 0 0 0]
             [0 1 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 1]
             [1 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 1 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 1]
             [0 0 0 1 0]];
```

are you sure you do not have some Russian letters in the name of the run configuration or anywhere else ?

Comment: Well, that is the issue - there are no non-latin characters in my code (added above) and the same is true for file names and paths. I don't think the issue is in the version I'm using (it is in Russian), but I have no clue what else might be provoking this error to occur

Comment: I have added an image above of the file names. The config is in english. The default Run Configuration (Конфигурация запуска) is in Russian, but I am sure it can't be renamed. The error message still pops up whether I run the English or the Russian named one. The system is in englsih. May it be the case that I need to change the language of the CPLEX itself?

Comment: Yes the configurations can be renamed. So try to rename it to config.